# Gather the Co-Ordinates & Draw them to Google Map

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to gather several coordinates from a php file and draw them to a google map making several markers. The data are gathered using the `.ajax` method of the `jquery` library. Here is my attempt:

allCoordinates.php:

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "root";
$db_database = "googlemapsdemo";

$connection = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$selectvalue = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['svalue']);

mysqli_select_db($connection, $db_database);

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM googlemapsdemo.vtiger_geocoding", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

$rows = array();

while ($allCoordinates = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $rows[] = array('latitude' => $allCoordinates[0], 'longitude' => $allCoordinates[1]);
}

$json = json_encode($rows);
print $json;



mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Maps Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"><script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var coordinates, parsedCoordinates;
        var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850); //Google map Coordinates
        var map;
        map_initialize(); // load map

        function map_initialize(){

            //Google map option
            var googleMapOptions = 
            { 
                center: mapCenter, // map center
                zoom: 17, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
                panControl: true, //enable pan Control
                zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
                zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
            },
                scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_container"), googleMapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: mapCenter,
                map: map
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content:"Hello World!"
            });

            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        }

        $(':submit').on('click', function() { // This event fires when a button is clicked
            $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
                  url: 'allCoordinates.php', // JQuery loads allCoordinates.php
                  dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
                  success: function(data) // Variable data contains the data we get from serverside
                  {
                      alert(data[0].latitude + " " + data[0].longitude);
                      coordinates = data;
                      parsedCoordinates = JSON.parse(coordinates);
                      update(parsedCoordinates);
                  }
            });
            return false; // keeps the page from not refreshing 
        });

        function update(markers){
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function(event){
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].latitude, markers[i].longitude),
                        map: map
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(markers[i].latitude + " " + markers[i].longitude);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }
            });
        }

    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="filters_container">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Zona</legend>
                    <form id="submitForm" method="post" action="">
                        <select>.......</select>
                        <button type="submit">Cerca</button>
                    </form>
                </fieldset>

        </div>
        <div id="map_container"></div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

the JSON returned is this:

```
[{"latitude":"45.648110","longitude":"11.497398"},
{"latitude":"45.511180","longitude":"11.511070"},
{"latitude":"45.649630","longitude":"12.304064"},
{"latitude":"45.722110","longitude":"11.435023"},
{"latitude":"45.391083","longitude":"11.276997"},
{"latitude":"45.691465","longitude":"11.483223"},
{"latitude":"45.659787","longitude":"11.795147"},
{"latitude":"45.720608","longitude":"11.453950"},
{"latitude":"45.718757","longitude":"11.333138"},
{"latitude":"45.607387","longitude":"11.497138"},
{"latitude":"46.099075","longitude":"12.160999"},
{"latitude":"45.523017","longitude":"10.152080"},
{"latitude":"45.408520","longitude":"10.838590"},
{"latitude":"45.717608","longitude":"11.462909"},
{"latitude":"45.395371","longitude":"11.274200"},
{"latitude":"45.555142","longitude":"11.543407"},
{"latitude":"45.693428","longitude":"11.446203"},
{"latitude":"44.661260","longitude":"10.886416"},
{"latitude":"45.530448","longitude":"11.499496"},
{"latitude":"45.530448","longitude":"11.499496"},
{"latitude":"22.318567","longitude":"114.179606"},
{"latitude":"45.443304","longitude":"10.952222"},
{"latitude":"45.836699","longitude":"12.014122"},
{"latitude":"45.803245","longitude":"11.355629"},
{"latitude":"45.722110","longitude":"11.435023"},
{"latitude":"45.803245","longitude":"11.355629"},
{"latitude":"45.836699","longitude":"12.014122"},
{"latitude":"45.779430","longitude":"11.429520"},
{"latitude":"45.803245","longitude":"11.355629"}]
```

The problem is that nothing changes; what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve. Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var coordinates, parsedCoordinates;
            var map;
            var marker;
            var markers = [];
            var clusterer;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            map_initialize(); // load map

            function map_initialize(){

                //Google map option
                var googleMapOptions = 
                {
                    center: coords,
                    zoom: 0, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
                    panControl: true, //enable pan Control
                    zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
                    scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_container"), googleMapOptions);
                //  Fit these bounds to the map
                map.fitBounds(bounds);

                // Marker Clusterer setup
                var mcOptions = {
                  gridSize : 50,
                  maxZoom : 15
                };


            }

            $(':submit').on('click', function() { // This event fires when a button is clicked

                $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
                      url: 'allCoordinates.php', // JQuery loads allCoordinates.php
                      dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
                      success: function(data) // Variable data contains the data we get from serverside
                      {
                          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude));

                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude),
                                map: map,
                                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png'
                            });

                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                                return function() {
                                    infowindow.setContent("Test");
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                }
                            })(marker, i));

                            markers.push(marker);
                          }
                          // Fit these bounds to the map
                          map.fitBounds(bounds);

                          clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
                      }
                });
                return false; // keeps the page from not refreshing 
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems I can see:

1) You're defining `map` within `initialize` which means that no other function can access and update it. Declare `map` outside of the functions.

2) You're not accessing the markers array properly; it's an array of objects so you need to use the keys to get the data instead:

3) You need to initialise the map differently (I would use google's own window.load event for this). Don't do it within in the jQuery doc.ready function.

4) When you're adding your markers you're doing so only if the map changes. Why? Get rid of that bit of code and your markers will be added to the map.

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/n4b4d/24/).

```
$(function () {

  // code for clicking the button.

});

var map;

function update(markers) {

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

    var lat = markers[i].latitude;
    var lng = markers[i].longitude;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, lat, lng) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(lat + " " + lng);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, lat, lng));

  }

}

function initialize(markers) {
  // your code
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is good answer because his code is completely wrong. Ajax call is done before map is created. And JSON output is an array of object, but `update()` expects an array of arrays. So there is no data for infowindow content.

Comment: I've fixed the javascript, but still I cannot understand where I am doing wrong, because the I can gather the JSON data but I cannot figure out how to draw all the coordinates into the map..

Comment: I've updated my answer again and provided you with a working JSFiddle.

Comment: The ajax call keeps retrieving data, how can I retrieve the data only once? Thanks!